# Undocumented SIM States in TelephonyManager

Tags: android, telephonymanager, sim-card

I'm working on an application where I want to read the SIM State, and I've been following along with Google's documentation on [getSimState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED).

Some of my users are returning values that are not referenced by a constant in the documentation listed. For example, I am getting `13` and `14` back. Any idea about these values or other undocumented, hidden SIM states that could be returned?

FWIW, I do believe these devices might be carrier locked, although I would expect `SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED` to return in this instance. I have one locked device where I can replicate this but I would love to know specifically why a different state is returned.

Comment: Android manufacturer can modify the source code and add features or states. So may be this is a manufacturer specific extension? You can try to extract the framework file from the device and decompile TelephonyManager class. May be it contains the state constants you are searching for.